# displaying images horizontally

Tags: css, alignment

The photos on my website are on top of each other and the other photos are displaying vertically. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

CSS:

```
#photo1{
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 210px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.img-with-text {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 200px;
}
.img-with-text:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: could you add the HTML as well?

Comment: Can you be a little less vague?

Comment: Without the HTML we can't help you, please add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following:
Try to add display: `inline-block` to your css on the image.
An example of what it does: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/d5sYM/ (credit goes to Kalle H. Väravas for this example)